# Why won't my cabbages form heads?

Tags: cabbage

I'm not an expert.  I try but probably do many things wrong.  That said, I am trying cabbages.  I live in zone 5, with a short growing season.  I started cabbages indoors in April from seeds.  They did well and I put them outside in may/June when they were established and had many big leaves.  It is now September.  They are growing tall and still producing leaves but only now beginning to ball up into a head.  If I wait it out, will they continue to form heads as the days get shorter?  What can I do differently to make them form up faster?  The picture shows one plant which is around 12 inches tall.  It seems to be balling up near the top.

.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check your seed package or other info. There are some very long season cabbages that do not head until late in the season. A truck farmer may plant 3 or 4 cabbages at the same time and have harvest times spread over a few months. Keep in mind cabbages' cousin , Brussel sprouts will generally not be ready in zone 5 until November.

Comment: The cabbage family are "cold season" plants which will withstand a lot of frost. I have eaten Brussel sprouts after the plants have been completely buried under snow for several weeks. In fact sprouts only fully develop there taste in below-freezing temperatures.

Comment: So, the consensus seems to be to give it at least another month?  Does this look normal for cabbages?

Comment: I would not put a time limit on it , I think cabbage is still good after a frost.